# How to pass a function to script in powershell?

Tags: powershell

**C:\tmp\run.ps1:**

```
function buildOne()
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$a,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$b
    )
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow "$a $b"
}

C:\tmp\_build.ps1 {$Function:buildOne}
```

**C:\tmp_build.ps1:**

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$buildOne
)

#&$buildOne "a" "b"
#Invoke-Command $buildOne -argumentlist "a", "b"
#Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $buildOne -argumentlist "a", "b"
```

The idea is to invoke the `buildOne` function passed as parameter from `run.ps1` to `_build.ps1`. Unfortunately, none of my attempts works. For some reason it just displays the function body rather than invokes it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke commands (and functions) by name as long as they are in scope:

```
C:\tmp_build.ps1 buildOne
```

tmp_build.ps1

```
& $buildOne a b
```

If you really want to pass the function definition then do it like this:

run.ps1

```
function buildOne()
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$a,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$b
    )
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow "$a $b"
}

.\tmp_build.ps1 $Function:buildOne
```

tmp_build.ps1

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$buildOne
)

$buildOne.Invoke("a", "b")
```

Comment: So the answer is impossible?

Comment: That is much better. Thanks.